# select top 3 highest number in each group in a table

Tags: oracle

There is a table, containing teachers, years, and lessons.
I have to find the top 3 of each group of lessons in each year (2005 to 2010) taught by the teacher

I grouped my table by lessons, year, teacher and counted the lessons 
for example for lesson1 if I have

```
lesson1  year1  teachera 20
lesson1  year1  teacherb 1
lesson1  year1  teacherd 10
lesson1  year1  teachere 5
lesson1  year1  teacherf 0
lesson1  year3  teacherc 1
lesson1  year4  teacherb 8
```

I have to get 20, 10 and 5 for year1
and 1 for year3 and 8 for year4

I have something around 40 lessons

Comment: Please provide the structure of the table and data. You may use http://sqlfiddle.com/ It would be much easier to help you.

Comment: Good for you, yasha! But it still would be easier to help you if you show us how your table look like.

Comment: made a table in sqlfiddle.com   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69d046/1/0

Comment: Do you use oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the analytical functions for achieving it

like below

```
SELECT Lesson, Year, Name, Count
  FROM
(
  select Lesson, Year, Name, Count,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Lesson, Year, Name ORDER BY Count DESC) as RK
  from A
)t
 WHERE RK <= 3;
```

Comment: Sudharsanan, why did you copy my answer? Does it mean it is correct?

Comment: And by the way, DENSE_RANK() would not work, it may give more than 3 rows (say, if there would be "lesson1 year1 teacherA 20 ", "lesson1 year1 teacherB 20 ", "lesson1 year1 teacherC 20 " and "lesson1 year1 teacherD 20 " - all four would be in the result).

Comment: @TimNanos yes the dense rank will give the top three highest number and it may contain the repeated value as he need only the top three highest value

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Oracle (as you marked your question), this will work:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
  select Lesson, Year, Name, Count,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Lesson, Year, Name ORDER BY Count DESC) as RN
  from A
)t
 WHERE RN <= 3;
```

It won't work in MySQL (as you created it in sqlfiddle), but I'm sure you get the idea to do the same there.

Answer (score 0):

That is how it worked for me, thank you

```
SELECT Lesson, Year, Name, Count
FROM
(
  SELECT Lesson, Year, Name, Count,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Lesson, Year, Name ORDER BY Count DESC) 
  as RK
  from A
) t
WHERE RK <= 3;
```